# why arduino can not write to server?

Tags: arduino-uno, web-server

i write a code for Arduino + SIM800 for connecting to server.
but it don't work!

```
SerialGsm.println("AT+CIPSEND=63\r\n");
delay( 1000 );
receive_message();
SerialGsm.print( "GET http://sasasas.ir.ir/hadi/signal.php?value=10" );
delay( 10000 );
receive_message();
```

all thing is true but "GET" can not retrun "OK".
it is arduino response:

---

AT

OK

Call Ready

SMS Ready
AT+CSTT="mtnirancell"

OK
AT+CIICR

OK
AT+CIFSR

100.65.157.141
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","sasasas.ir",80

OK

CONNECT OK
AT+CIPSEND=63

> GET http://sasasas.ir/hadi/signal.php?value=10
>
> ---

"get" dont have response.what is wrong in this code?

Comment: Learn the proper format of a GET request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you only have half of the first line of a GET request. Secondly the half you do have is badly formatted.

A GET request does *NOT* look like this:

```
GET http://jalambadani.ir/hadi/signal.php?value=10
```

A GET request *DOES* look like this:

```
GET /hadi/signal.php?value=10 HTTP/1.1
Host: jalambadani.ir
Connection: close
[extra blank line]
```

If you don't send the correct data you can't expect to get any response back.  You should learn the basics of what you are trying to do instead of just throwing random text a a web server.

---

Here is a full transcript of a GET request to your URL:

```
$ telnet jalambadani.ir 80
Trying 185.211.56.148...
Connected to jalambadani.ir.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /hadi/signal.php?value=10 HTTP/1.1
Host: jalambadani.ir
Connection: close

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 25 Jun 2019 22:47:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.35
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Connection: Upgrade, close
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

New record created successfullyConnection closed by foreign host.
```

In code that would be:

```
SerialGsm.print("AT+CIPSEND=83\r\n");
delay(1000); // I hate that. Look for a proper OK instead.
SerialGsm.print("GET /hadi/signal.php?value=15 HTTP/1.1\r\n");
SerialGsm.print("Host: jalambadani.ir\r\n");
SerialGsm.print("Connection: close\r\n");
SerialGsm.print("\r\n);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i am electrical student and i don,t know about http...but i will try learn it.

i test your answer but it don,t work yet:|

"GET" don,t answer to me.@Majenko

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with it. You are talking in HTTP.

Comment: Did you try majenko's suggestion - which looks like it does work - running against your server - using telnet?? Once you see how that works translate that to your arduinon code. Don't reach for the final solution in the first attempt if it is too far away. Take it one step at a time. Copy majenko's telnet example -> learn the protocol. Then transfer the protocol to your app.

Comment: yes i use of majenko's suggestion.




      SerialGsm.print("AT+CIPSEND=50\r\n");
      delay( 3000 );
      receive_message();
      SerialGsm.print( "GET /hadi/signal.php?value=15 HTTP/1.1" );
      delay( 3000 );
      receive_message();



not work.

Comment: @hadisamani1996 What about the Host: and Connection: headers, along with the extra blank line? They are all part of the request. You have to send all the request.

Comment: i resolve it with your help@Majenko
i have 2 mistake.
first you saw and when i use of this line it solved.
**********
SerialGsm.print( "GET /hadi/signal.php?value=150 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: jalambadani.ir\r\n\r\n" );
***********
two
next of " GET command " i use of a little delay.
i increase it a little and next solved my problem
thank you

Comment: Since Majenko helped you, you should accept his answer by clicking the little grey checkmark (tick mark) next to his answer.

Comment: nitpicking: why not `println`?

Comment: Depending on the system println could end with `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n`. Better to be explicit here.

Comment: HTTP specification requires \r\n. Arduino println() adds \r\n on all cores

Comment: @Juraj that can't be guaranteed. Certainly all cores *should* do it but there are so many written by so many different people with different skill sets that it can't be 100% guaranteed.

Comment: Print class is copied. there is nothing to change in println. if some core would change it, it would have an issue in the tracker immediately. basic examples of networking libraries would not work